# Is it safe to define a context manager around a nested function?

Tags: python, contextmanager

For a third party library* I have to provide a function which consumes some data. My implementation of the consumption requires the data to be posted to an API. So I came up with this structure below:

```py
def consumer_provider():

    with HttpClient() as http_client:
        
        def consumer(data):
            http_client.post(data)

        return consumer
```

So I can present the function to the third party lib like so:

```py
third_party_lib.add(consumer=consumer_provider())
```

In my tests it works quite well, but is this legit? When do I have to expect that the context manager releases the resource (in this case the connection pool)?

* loguru in this case, but it should not really matter for the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context manager. In the code you wrote, the `HTTPClient` you created stays alive because the function it returns maintains a reference to it, even though the variable `http_client` defined in `consumer_provider` goes out of scope.

However, `HTTPClient.__exit__` is still called before `consumer_provider` returns, so the consumer function may not work as intended.

You may want to do something like

```
def consumer_provider():
    http_client = HttpClient()
    def consumer(data):
        with http_client:
            http_client.post(data)
    return consumer
```

which ensures that the `HttpClient` object stays "hidden" inside the closure, but its `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods aren't called until the function gets called. (Whether the client can be used by multiple function calls also depends on the definition of `HttpClient`.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, indeed I tested it with another http client implementation and my setup failed miserably :D.